# Colocación de rectangulo en Android

Tags: java, android

Como podría colocar un rectángulo en la parte inferior de la pantalla?:

```
    private void cargarJuego() {
     r = new Rect(100,100,200,200);
     escenario = new Escenario(r);
     setContentView(new GameView(this,escenario));
}
```

Comment: La pantalla esta en portrait,es decir,en vertical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de comentar como realizar lo que preguntas es importante revises el mètodo [drawRect()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRect(android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint)) de la clase [Canvas](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawRect(android.graphics.Rect,%20android.graphics.Paint)) , el cual tiene varias implementaciones, puedes ver que puede recibir los puntos izquierdo, arriba, derecho, y fondo así como el objeto Paint:

```
void drawRect (float left, 
                float top, 
                float right, 
                float bottom, 
                Paint paint)
```

Los puntos indican la posición en la cual se dibujara el rectangulo (o cuadrado), en el caso de android las coordenadas 0,0 inician en la posición superior izquierda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

similar al cuarto cuadrante de un plano cartesiano:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes crear una clase que cree tu rectangulo, en este caso iniciara el dibujado del mismo en la coordenada 0,0 y como ejemplo 400 pixeles de ancho por 200 de alto:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.View;

public class Rectangle extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public Rectangle(Context context) {
        super(context);            
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 400, 200, paint);
    }

}
```

y mostrarlo en tu `Activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(rectangle);


}
```

Teniendo como resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en cambio si queremos que se muestre en la parte inferior podemos aumentar el valor de `top` y `bottom` para que posicione verticalmente hacia abajo.

He visto que lo que deseas es realizar un juego, por lo tanto te daré un ejemplo de como mover el rectángulo, mediante `drag and drop`, usando la clase anterior para crear el rectángulo:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Move the rectangle!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Mediante `OnTouchListener` , al tocar la vista y arrastrarla, esta se moverá en la posición deseada, modificando su posición.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private RelativeLayout rootLayout;
    private int _xDelta;
    private int _yDelta;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //activity_main, debe contenerse dentro del layout activity_main.xml
        rootLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(getApplicationContext());
        rootLayout.addView(rectangle);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
        rectangle.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        rectangle.setOnTouchListener(this);

    }

    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        final int X = (int) event.getRawX();
        final int Y = (int) event.getRawY();
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                _xDelta = X - lParams.leftMargin;
                _yDelta = Y - lParams.topMargin;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.leftMargin = X - _xDelta;
                layoutParams.topMargin = Y - _yDelta;
                layoutParams.rightMargin = -250;
                layoutParams.bottomMargin = -250;
                view.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
                break;
        }
        rootLayout.invalidate();
        return true;
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]